# Loosing strokes when merging for coloring

Tags: adobe-illustrator, merge

I am about to color my drawing, but when I want to Merge the strokes, some of them disappears? What am I missing here, besides strokes?

Before merge:
[image]

After merge:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your layer structure, or the outline view?

Comment: What kind of "merge" are you doing?  Are you trying to create a combined path using one of the pathfinder operations?  If so, which pathfinder operation are you using? Please edit your question and add details as it's unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "merge", are you applying a pathfinder type?

You don't need to do that,

- If the drawing is a path, select it and **Expand** it. Keep the original path in another layer if you prefer.
- Get the **Shape Builder Tool**

[image: shape builder tool]

- Click in each part you want to color
- Select each one and fill

[image: gif]